# excel how to show current month and year with space

Tags: excel

i want current month and year in a cell with space in between, I have used the formula =TEXT(AG1,"MMMM")&YEAR(AG1) but unable to get space in between in it.

Comment: Have you tried CONCATENATE ?

Answer (score 2):

```
=TEXT(AG1,"MMMM")& " " & YEAR(AG1)
```

simpler:

```
=TEXT(AG1, "MMMM YYYY")
```